# Git status shows an untracked "master" file

Tags: git

I´m trying to understand what is this untracked file and why is it there:

```
   $ git status
   On branch master
   Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

   Untracked files:
     (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

           master

   nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: I'm guessing that you mistyped a git command and created a file. Take a look at the contents of the file. It should give you a clue.

Answer (score 0):

`Untracked files` are those newly added files which are not still merged/committed/sync with upstream. Easy words `Untracked files` are newly added change files.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways that a rogue untracked file can end up appearing in your `git status` output.  One way is that you, either deliberately or otherwise, created this file while working on the `master` branch or some other branch.  Another possibility is that this file is an artifact and was created by something else.

In any case, just type `ls -la` from your current location in Git bash and figure out what this file is.  You may also type `vi master` to view this file in Vim.

Answer (score 0):

`master` is a file which has not been added to the repository.  Maybe it is a built file?

If it is something which should be in the repository, then do as git suggests:  `git add master`.   If not, perhaps you want to add it to `.gitignore` so `master` can be there and be used, but *git* won't try to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

Un-tracked files are the files which are modified but not added and committed to your branch in which you are working. If there are any un-committed files Git shows them untracked, usually in red color.

To add these untracked files you have to use below commands before that you have to switch to your branch:

- git add "File name"
- git commit -m "Commit message"
- git push
- git status

Noe Git will show committed files in green color.

Generally we add source files(eg: .java files) and maven or ant, gradle configuration files to our branch. But we do not add IDE specific configuration files such as .project file in case of eclipse.